# Parse.com login with javaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

Can't figure out why the login is not working. Here's the `javaScript`code:

```
Parse.initialize("app id", "app key");

function fazerLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('senha').value;

    alert(username);
    alert(password);

    Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: function(user) {
            alert("deu certo");
            // Do stuff after successful login.
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("erro");
            alert(user + error);
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        }
    });
}

var botao = document.querySelector('#botao');
botao.onclick = fazerLogin;
```

The function gets called because I see the alerts with the correct login and password. I can login in iOS sdk with no problem, but it doesn't work on `javaScript`, I'm not sure what I'm missing. At the end of `html`document inside `body` I have:

```
     <!-- PARSE.COM JS -->
    <script src="assets/js/parse-1.2.18.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
```

Even if I put the username and password as strings, like: `Parse.User.logIn("username", "password", {`, it still doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

The `login` works when I call it outside function:

```
Parse.User.logIn("email", "PASS", {
        success: function(user) {
            console.log("Deu certo");
            console.log(user);
            return true;
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            console.log(user + error);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

HTML form

```
<form role="form" id="formulario-login">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback lg left-feedback no-label">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-lg rounded" placeholder="Usuário" autofocus id="usuario">
                  <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback lg left-feedback no-label">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control no-border input-lg rounded" placeholder="Senha" id="senha">
                  <span class="fa fa-unlock-alt form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="i-yellow-flat"> Manter-me conectado.
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-perspective btn-block" id="botao">LOGIN</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can we assume that the app id and app key strings are correct on your end? Also, when you're saying it doesn't work, what do you mean? Does it end up in the error block? Does it alert you of an error message? Give you an exception?

Comment: App keys are correct. I just get `[object Object][object Object]`on console log. that call is in the login error. So I believe the login function executes.

Comment: instead of `alert` I `have console.log(error)`, that is different in the code above. sorry.

Comment: Try using `debugger;` in the beginning of the method, that way you can use your browser to debug line by line, and drill into the objects. From what I'm understanding though, if the app keys and login credentials are right, and the function is executing, it isn't a problem with the JS, it may indeed be something from the back-end.

Comment: The login works if I call it outside `function`.

Comment: In that case, what has to be happening is that when you're retrieving data via `document.getElementById('usuario').value;`, the data isn't clean. Could you add the HTML for those two elements as well?

Comment: I guess the problem is how I call the function on last two lines (button click), because if instead of button click, I go with `fazerLogin();`, the function gets called and it works.

Comment: Try changing your button type value to this: `<button type="button"` instead of `<button type="submit"`

Comment: http://marionette-todo.parseapp.com/    debug that one. maybe as sample it will help u

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't understand the difference between two types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the problem was that you were using `<button type="submit"` instead of `<button type="button"`.

The core difference between the two is that the `submit` type will actually submit the form and the data you have in your HTML form before executing your function, whereas the `button` type will give you a button that does not submit, but will fire all events assigned to it (such as your `onclick`).